# QLCDNumber in Qt

Tags: qt

I'm using a QLCDNumber in Qt and when the number changes the previous number does not get cleared so I eventually end up with 888 and the changing values can not be seen.  Is there anything I need to do to clear the previous value? Thanks

Comment: Qt version? OS? I just did an example and it works nicely with Qt Creator and Qt 5.2

Comment: I am using Qt 5.1.1 with Qt Creator 2.8.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt 5.2 and Qt Creator 3.0 on Windows 7 works perfectly for me (and should for you too). You can start from a basic example and build on top of it:

1. Create a default Qt Widget project;
   [image]
2. Add a QSpinBox and a QLCDNumber;
3. Connect the QSpingBox valueChanged signal to QLCDNumber display slot.
   [image]

Comment: I tried this on my current project and it gave me the same problem. I tried it again on a new project and it seems to work fine. So there must be something in my current program that is causing the problem.

Comment: Is there anything that could prevent widgets refresh? This is a minimal example that should help you find the problem hopefully.